# Одномерный динамический массив C#

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

Имеется вот такая задача:

> Случайные числа в диапазоне от -5 до 5 разложить по двум массивам: в
> одни помещать только положительные, во второй - только отрицательные.
> Числа, равные нулю, игнорировать. Вывести на экран все сгенерированные
> случайные числа и элементы обоих массивов.

Не могу разобраться в чем ошибка и правильно ли я вообще делаю

```
int p = 1;
int n = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int[] poloz = new int[p];
    int[] otric = new int[n];

    int ch = Random();
    if (ch > 0)
    {
        poloz[p - 1] = ch;
        p++;
    }
    else if (ch < 0)
    {
        otric[n - 1] = ch;
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот такое решение мне предлагается задачей:
*Изначально оба массива пусты.
*Присвоим двум разным переменным-индексам массивов нули.
*В цикле выполняем следующие действия.
Генерируем случайное число и выводим его на экран.
Если очередное число положительное, то увеличиваем индекс массива на единицу и записываем в соответствующую ячейку это число.
Если же генерируется отрицательное число, то увеличиваем индекс массива отрицательных чисел и записываем в массив число.

Comment: Можно использовать коллнкцию `List<T>`, список позволяет динамически добавлять в него элементы. И у вас назания метода `Random()` конфликтует с названием класса `Random`, переназовите метод так, чтобы никто не путался.

Comment: @aepot Меня больше смущает наличие слова _массив_ в задании. Там не сказано коллекция. С таким же успехом можно взять `LinkedList` и уйти от массивов даже косвенно.

Comment: Это задача из Задачника по программированию. Не расчитано на конкретный язык программирования. Есть пример решения для C++ и Python

Comment: @АнатолийИванов а в решении для С++ вектор используется?

Comment: Ну если из задачника, то на C# решается в 3 строки. `Random rnd = new Random(); int[] positive = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 20).Select(x => rnd.Next(1, 6)).ToArray(); int[] negative = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 20).Select(x => rnd.Next(-5, 0)).ToArray();` или так `int[] array = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 20).Select(x => rnd.Next(-5, 6)).ToArray(); int[] negative = array.Where(x => x < 0).ToArray(); int[] positive = array.Where(x => x > 0).ToArray();`

Comment: @aepot `array.Where(e => e != 0).GroupBy(e => e > 0)`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников можно и так, да

Comment: @aepot [вот задание](https://taskcode.ru/array/two-arrays) которое решал автор. И там речь явно про массивы :-)

Comment: Зачем удаляете свои [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1252851/213987) после того, как вам помогли?

Comment: Там в коде всего лишь опечатка была в кавычках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, стоит поместить массивы вне тела цикла и задать им размер. Если нужен именно массив, то вариант только изменять ему размер на каждое добавление. Внутри [`Array.Resize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-5.0) выделение массива нового размера и копирование:

```
int p = 1;
int n = 1;

int[] poloz = new int[0];
int[] otric = new int[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int ch = Random();
    if (ch > 0)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref poloz, p);
        poloz[p - 1] = ch;
        p++;
    }
    else if (ch < 0)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref otric, n);
        otric[n - 1] = ch;
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: В этом и сложность, мне нужно не создать определенный массив (как в примере у Вас 20), а чтобы его размер увеличивался в появлением подходящего числа.

Comment: @АнатолийИванов динамические структуры я так понимаю не предлагать?

Comment: @АнатолийИванов обновил ответ

Comment: я думаю для меня это пока сложно

Comment: @АнатолийИванов я думал это для учебного задания. Для реальной жизни это тоже странный подход :-)

Answer (score 3):

ты хочешь использовать динамический массив, но в C# на самом деле такого нет.
есть только структуры данных которые похожи на динамический массив

```
var poloz = new List<int>(15);
var otric = new List<int>(15);
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int ch = Random();
    if (ch > 0)
    {
        poloz.Add(ch);
    }
    else if (ch < 0)
    {
        otric.Add(ch);
    }
}
```

у класса `List` есть метод `Count` - он и есть твой "динамический" размер массива

Comment: Вот это я и хотел узнать, возможно ли это реализовать в C#. Спасибо

Comment: @АнатолийИванов галочку поставить мне в ответ не забудь)

Comment: `List` это разве структура? По-моему это класс, и он не массив, а список, или даже коллекция. С массивом у него мало общего.

Comment: @aepot почему мало общего? В шарпе Лист это враппер на масив. Это тот же ArrayList джавы.

Comment: У вас ошибка, вынесите из цикла создание списков.